# AngularJS .openModel() reurns error not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, materialize

I have a project which combines AngularJS and Materialize CSS which opens a model with id `#modal-some-form` using AngularJS `$('#model-some-form').openModel();`.

Now I have another project with similar code, same JQuery, AngularJS and Materialize versions, but when trying to open the model I get:

> Error: $(...).openModel is not a function

The code for the model is:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="modal-bango-form" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 id="modal-bango-title">Andika bango jipya</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <label>Ujumbe wa bango unahusu nini?</label>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <select class="browser-default">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Chagua</option>
                      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                    <textarea id="ujumbe" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                    <label for="ujumbe">Ujumbe wa bango</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue-grey" ng-click="createBango()"><i class="material-icons left">add</i> Tuma</a>
                    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue-grey" ng-click="closeBangoForm()"><i class="material-icons left">close</i> Ghairi</a>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- // end of #modal-form -->
</div>
```

And the code for my Angular script is:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.openBangoForm = function(){
        $("#modal-bango-form").openModel();
    }

    $scope.closeBangoForm = function(){
        $('#modal-bango-form').closeModel();
    }

});
```

Neither closeModel() nor openModel(), but on the other project it runs well.

Please assist.

Regards

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you should not use jQuery methods in controller. Also it shoukd probably be openMod**a**l.

Comment: You do realize a fairy dies every-time you use jQuery in a controller? How are you calling those two methods? Has the DOM rendered and those elements with the id present when they run? Don't forget angular dynamically renders things. You should put those jQuery calls in a directive. Thats where they belong, its also why directives provide you with a jQuery/jqlite object.

Comment: check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083395/materializecss-modal-error-openmodal-is-not-a-function/40937195#40937195

Answer (score 0):

I came to realize before @dfsq replied to my question that i was misspelled the modal with model.

Fixing the line `$('#modal-bango-form').openModel();` with `$('#modal-bango-form').openModal();` fixed the problem.

It's dumb, but took me a day to figure out, duh!...

Hope will help someone there....