# MaterializeCss modal Error openModal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, materialize

I have all requirements Jquery, Materialize.js sitting above my Js file however I get the warning openModal is not a function..I checked the modal name is right and I can run Materialize.toast so I know Materialize.js is working. Triggering with the button does not call the modal either. Here is the code..

Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/materialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/video.js"></script>
<script src="/js/admin.js"></script>
```

Trigger:

```
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
```

Modal:

```
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
 var modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
  modal.openModal();
$('#modal1').leanModal();
$('#modal1').openModal();
```

Answer (score 4):

Materialize functions needs Jquery Elements.
getElementById() - Gives us DOM Object.

```
//You can either convert this Dom object to Jquery

var modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
var jquerymodal = $(modal);  //convert to jQuery Element
jquerymodal.openModal();


//Or just use Jquery Element like

$('#modal1').openModal();
```

Comment: I tried to give it Jquery as well didn't accept that either. Responds:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).openModal is not a function

Answer (score 3):

Ok I had the same issue and I fixed it by changing up the call to open the modal and the initialization.

If you had the same issue as I, check out the most recent documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/modals.html)

This may be new - openModal() is not used here.

Initialization:

```
<script>
   try {
       try {
      $('#modalId').modal();
  } catch (e) {
      console.info('loading modal auto-initialized..');
  }
   }
</script>
```

I added the try/catch because sometimes this is not needed

Implementation:

```
$('#modalID').modal('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the minified file in materialize/dist folder instead of materialize/js.

Run with: 
     $('#elementId').modal();
     $('#elementId').modal('show');

Just this way it worked.

EDIT:

In fact, it didn't work in production environment.

So I did this:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.showModal = function() {

        var self = this;
        try {
            this.modal();
            self.modal('open');
        } catch (err) {
            try{
                self.openModal();
            } catch (err2) {
                console.error("Something went wrong - cannot open modal.");             
            }
        }
    }


    $.fn.hideModal = function() {

        var self = this;
        try {
            this.modal();
            self.modal('close');
        } catch (err) {
            try{
                self.closeModal();
            } catch (err2) {
                console.error("Something went wrong - cannot close modal.");                
            }
        }
    }


}( jQuery ));
```

Use just: $('#modal').showModal()